# Block SE sites from bugmenot.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-accounts, security

http://www.bugmenot.com/view/stackoverflow.com

This is a troll heaven and there is no good reason for using a shared account from bugmenot on Stack Overflow or any other SE site.

Blocking a site can be requested on http://www.bugmenot.com/report.php - however, it needs to be done by a SE staff member/developer as they require you to create a file with a certain name to prove that you actually own the site.

Comment: `This is a troll heaven` And Stack Overflow isn't???

Comment: @YannisRizos Not to this extent, no. #AntiJokeChicken ;)

Comment: Having all the trolls use the same account that can be easily suspended, instead of each one using an unregistered account sounds pretty convenient to me ;-)

Comment: Do not forget http://www.bugmenot.com/view/serverfault.com either.

Comment: @MadScientist I'm a bit torn on this. There's at least one account I know of that actually got 200-something reputation before getting signed into by a troll. So in theory one of these accounts could gain privileges we don't want to just let anyone use. (Or a higher rep user could share out their login info for whatever reason, which would be even worse.) Sure, anyone can potentially share their login at any time, but why make it easy? :)

Comment: @AnnaLear My comment wasn't meant entirely serious. Having an account with actual privileges openly available for everyone is very problematic. Another reason why I would be a great fan of a "rollback all user actions since ..." tool for mods.

Comment: Yes, BMN is still active (and actually incredibly useful for crappy register-to-read forums/sites).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So that request form has been broken for a long time, but they (recently?) rolled out a new one: http://bugmenot.com/removal.php

Since that doesn't require any fancy footwork server-side, I went ahead and submitted SO, SU, SF and SE along with explanations for why the corresponding BMN pages are currently filled with unusable accounts...

These have now all been delisted.

Comment: confirmed, it still works! By that I mean they have a nice "why this site is not allowed" page that makes sense.